# UITableView with TableHeaderView wont scroll to top on status bar tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, xamarin.ios

Note that this is in Xamarin.iOS (C#).  However, the concept should be the same.

I have a a few UIViewControllers each with a UITableView containing a TableHeaderView.  These UITableViews won't scroll to the top on the status bar tap.

When I take the TableHeaderView out, the UITableView scrolls to the top on the status bar tap just fine.

For my UITableViews, I have explicitly set ScrollsToTop to true, and overridden the ShouldScrollToTop method in the UITableViewSource to always return true.

No luck. Why is the TableHeaderView keeping my UITableView from scrolling to the top on the status bar tap?

Comment: Tell me more about your TableHeaderView.

Comment: The TableHeaderView has UIImageViews, UILabels,

Comment: What kind of class is it?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that I had a text view with ScrollsToTop enabled in my TableHeaderView.  This was keeping the status bar tap from working.